# Dryer plug problem

Tags: dryer

I just got a new electric clothes dryer to replace a gas dryer. Unfortunately, I don't have an outlet that will fit the plug that came with the dryer. 
Can I just buy a adapter for it that can go from the dryer to a regular plug ?

Comment: Can you please edit this question so that it makes sense? Please use punctuation and separate your sentences.

Comment: While more expensive than electric dryers, gas dryers dry faster. They also cost less to run, more than saving you the higher initial cost. So, you might consider returning the electric and picking up a gas model.

Comment: *Bill is jealous of gas dryer hookups

Answer (score 9):

Assuming this is in North America, **No**, you can't plug an electric dryer into a regular plug. An electric dryer requires 208-240 volts and possibly as much as 30 amps of current, and a standard plug supplies only 110-120 volts and 15-20 amps.

You will need an electrician (or knowledgeable acquaintance) to run high-current wiring and install the correct plug for your dryer.

Alternatively, you could return the dryer and replace it with a new gas dryer.

Comment: An electric dryer in North America is a 120/240V, 30A circuit. But you are correct, there is NO WAY to use an electric dryer on a "standard" household receptacle.